# Mocking while loop

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I need to mock a while loop to run just once however my setup makes it run infinite times as I think it returns true always.

My Set up:

```
var loginName = "12345";

cacheRepository.Setup(m => m.AddString(string.Format("{0}_{1}", Resources.ResetCodeCacheKey, randomCode), loginName)).Returns(true);
```

While loop in method:

```
while (_cacheRepository.AddString(string.Format("{0}_{1}", Resources.ResetCodeCacheKey, code), userLoginName))
{
    //.........
}
```

Add String implementation:

```
public virtual bool AddString(string key, string value)
{
    if (!ExistsKey(key))
    {
        Cache.AddString(key, value);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I set up my method to return true just once? A code snippet will be helpful.Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SetupSequence` to setup the mocked member to return the desired results.

For example say you have the following interface

```
public interface IInterface {
    bool AddString(string key, string value);
}
```

The setup would look like

```
var cacheRepository = new Mock<IInterface>();
cacheRepository
    .SetupSequence(m => m.AddString(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(true)
    .Returns(false);
```

When the mocked member is called the first time is will return `true` and then `false` the second time.

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the mocking framework.

> Setting up a member to return different values / throw exceptions on sequential calls:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.SetupSequence(f => f.GetCount())
    .Returns(3)  // will be returned on 1st invocation
    .Returns(2)  // will be returned on 2nd invocation
    .Returns(1)  // will be returned on 3rd invocation
    .Returns(0)  // will be returned on 4th invocation
    .Throws(new InvalidOperationException());  // will be thrown on 5th invocation
```

Comment: ...And just to add a caution that if you *debug* tests which use SetupSequence, beware that the debugger fetching values counts as an invocation. This is more of an issue when using SetupSequence for properties than when doing it for methods, as is the case here; but I thought it worth mentioning. The clue is that the test behaves differently when run compared to being debugged. Such behaviour is an example of a [Heisenbug](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).